# Nested foreach gets same value every time

Tags: c#, foreach

So i have in here 3 foreach's.
I jump out of one to get to the other but, when a reloop happends the second and third foreach always get the same value over and over again, first value of the list.
Any solutions? I want that it takes the second value of the list on the second loop, the 3th value of the list on the third loop, etc....
Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hafd53q9u4e2tz/Naamloos.png

```
foreach (LineUp ssc in list)
{
    Row r = new Row() { RowIndex = rownumber };
    Cell c1 = new Cell() { CellReference = "A" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(ssc.Date) };
    Cell c2 = new Cell() { CellReference = "B" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(ssc.From) };
    Cell c3 = new Cell() { CellReference = "C" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(ssc.Until) };
    r.Append(c1, c2, c3);
    data.Append(r);

    foreach (Stage ssc2 in stages)
    {                      
            Row r2 = new Row() { RowIndex = rownumber };
            Cell c4 = new Cell() { CellReference = "D" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.Number, CellValue = new CellValue(ssc2.Name) };
            r2.Append(c4);
            data.Append(r2);
    }

    foreach (Band ssc3 in bands)
    {
            Row r3 = new Row() { RowIndex = rownumber };
            Cell c5 = new Cell() { CellReference = "E" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.Number, CellValue = new CellValue(ssc3.Name) };
            r3.Append(c5);
            data.Append(r3);
            break;
    }
    break;
}                   
rownumber++;
```

Comment: Where are `stages` and `bands` ever updated?

Comment: Could you take out all excess code, make a simple example where you have just three elements in each of `list`, `stages`, and `bands` (say 1,2,3) and show what you want the output to be? I am confused by your description. It sounds like you **don't** want 111 112 113 121 122 123 131 132 133 211 212 213... ??  But that's what conventional nested loops will do. Maybe you need a single loop, then access the nth element of each?

Comment: `foreach` always starts from the beginning of its container. If you do not want to start at the beginning, make an explicit iterator object, which would preserve the position across the loop boundaries.

Comment: put the rownumber++ inside the outer most foreach... its outside its scope.

Comment: @akanksha - I think that relates to the "extra brace" that Alex Walker identified...

Comment: list stages and band are in the ctor of my vm. the first row goes all well and i get all things from the list, the second and third row always repeat the first item in the list. I can't place it in a single loop because they are too different (lineup, stage, band). The rownumber++ is already in the outer most foreach.

Comment: I have uploaded a screenshot of my outcome. https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hafd53q9u4e2tz/Naamloos.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are iterating `stages` and `bands` each time, but breaking after the first value.

It *sounds* like you want to `Zip` the three collections:

```
var zippedList = list.Zip(stages, (l, s) => new {ssc = l, stage = s})
                     .Zip(bands, (ls, b) => new {ls.ssc, ls.stage,  band = b)};
foreach (var item in zippedList)
{
    Row r = new Row() { RowIndex = rownumber };
    Cell c1 = new Cell() { CellReference = "A" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(item.ssc.Date) };
    Cell c2 = new Cell() { CellReference = "B" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(item.ssc.From) };
    Cell c3 = new Cell() { CellReference = "C" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(item.ssc.Until) };
    r.Append(c1, c2, c3);
    data.Append(r);

    Row r2 = new Row() { RowIndex = rownumber };
    Cell c4 = new Cell() { CellReference = "D" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.Number, CellValue = new CellValue(item..stage.Name) };
    r2.Append(c4);

    data.Append(r2);

    Row r3 = new Row() { RowIndex = rownumber };
    Cell c5 = new Cell() { CellReference = "E" + rownumber, DataType = CellValues.Number, CellValue = new CellValue(item.band.Name) };
    r3.Append(c5);

    data.Append(r3);

    rownumber++;
}
```

Comment: hello, this works but returns me wrong code. Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k470ooo9kg8xa7e/wrong.png I think the stage is wrong too, but just lucky it's the right one this time

Comment: Run it in the debugger and see if you can find the issue - `Zip` lines up collections side by side and returns one item form each collection in order.  Without knowing more about your sources or expectations I can't give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

foreach is syntactic sugar around (approximately)

```
var enumerator = stages.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
    var ssc2 = enumerator.Current;
    // your loop code
}
```

So your nested foreach loops are getting a new enumerator and starting over at the first value each time. You probably want something more along the lines of

```
for (var rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < list.Length; rowNumber++)
{
    var ssc = list[rowNumber];
    // work with ssc

    var ssc2 = stages[rowNumber];
    // work with ssc2

    var ssc3 = bands[rowNumber];
    // work with ssc3
}
```

plus appropriate bounds checking and assuming that list, stages, and bands are indexable (e.g. they are arrays, lists, or something similar).

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. When i try that i get this. https://www.dropbox.com/s/k470ooo9kg8xa7e/wrong.png

Comment: If you are getting the same results with both this and D Stanley's code as your comments indicate, then there's clearly something off about how you're creating list, stages, and bands. If you can post that code maybe we can get a bit further.